# I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: html, wordpress, parsing

can some help me figure out why I'm getting the error below, seem to be the end  that is giving me the problem?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandboxwp\wp-content\themes\webpromo\parts\slider.php on line 44

```html
<?php
$slides = array(); 
$args = array( 'tag' => 'slide', 'nopaging'=>true, 'posts_per_page'=>5 );
$slider_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) {
        $slider_query->the_post();
        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
            $temp = array();
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'full', true);
            $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
            $temp['title'] = get_the_title();
            $temp['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
            $temp['image'] = $thumb_url;
            $slides[] = $temp;
        }
    }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

  <?php if(count($slides) > 0) { ?>

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php for($i=0;$i<count($slides);$i++) { ?>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if($i==0) { ?>class="active"
        <?php } ?>></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <?php $i=0; foreach($slides as $slide) { extract($slide); ?>
      <div class="item <?php if($i == 0) { ?>active<?php } ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>
            <?php echo $title; ?>
          </h3>
          <p>
            <?php echo $excerpt; ?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php $i++; } ?>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" target="_blank" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" target="_blank" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be a little more careful with your indentations. I cleaned it up a bit for you and it made the answer quite apparent: You're missing a closing brace `}` for your `if( count( $slides ) > 0 ){` statement:

```
<?php
    $slides = array(); 

    $args = array( 'tag' => 'slide', 'nopaging'=>true, 'posts_per_page'=>5 );

    $slider_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $slider_query->have_posts() ){
        while( $slider_query->have_posts() ){
            $slider_query->the_post();

            if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
                $temp        = array();
                $thumb_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumb_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'full', true );
                $thumb_url   = $thumb_array[0];

                $temp['title']   = get_the_title();
                $temp['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
                $temp['image']   = $thumb_url;

                $slides[] = $temp;
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    if( count( $slides ) > 0 ){ ?>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $slides ); $i++ ){ ?>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php if( $i==0 ){ ?>class="active"<?php } ?>></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <?php $i = 0 ; foreach( $slides as $slide ){ extract( $slide ); ?>
                <div class="item <?php if( $i == 0 ) { ?>active<?php } ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                        <p><?php echo $excerpt; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" target="_blank" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" target="_blank" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
        </div>
    <?php }
?>
```